# Usort in Opencart

Tags: php, usort, opencart-3

I'm trying to order an array like this in my opencart 3.0.2:

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> array(3) 
    { 
       ["name"]=> string(5) "Name1" 
       ["download_id"]=> int(1) 
       ["event_date"]=> string(10) "05/05/2018" 
    } 
[1]=> array(3) 
    { 
       ["name"]=> string(5) "Name2" 
       ["download_id"]=> int(2) 
       ["event_date"]=> string(10) "05/06/2018" 
    } 
[2]=> array(3) 
    { 
       ["name"]=> string(5) "Name3" 
       ["download_id"]=> int(3) 
       ["event_date"]=> string(10) "01/05/2018" 
    } 
[3]=> array(3) 
    { 
       ["name"]=> string(5) "Name4" 
       ["download_id"]=> int(4) 
       ["event_date"]=> string(10) "02/05/2018" 
    } 
}
```

I'm using USORT to order this array like this:

```
usort($download_teste['teste'], "sortByDate")
```

My SortByDate function is this one:

```
function sortByDate($a, $b) {
   $first = $this->formatDateDownloadForTest($a['event_date']);
   $second = $this->formatDateDownloadForTest($b['event_date']);

   if ($first == $second) {
     return 0;
   }

   return ($first < $second) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Also I use this function formatDateDownloadForTest, to get the date and transform the original date like d/m/Y to Ymd in string, so the date 05/05/2018 will become 20180505, in order to compare them and return correctly. This function I tested and it's ok!

```
function formatDateDownloadForTest($date){
   $insertedDate = explode("/", $date);
   $insertedDate = $insertedDate[2].$insertedDate[1].$insertedDate[0];

   return $insertedDate;
}
```

For some reason it's not working, I want to know what I'm doing wrong here because it doesn't change the array order in any way.

Thank you for your time!
Bica

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered what is the problem:

```
usort($download_teste['teste'], array($this, "sortByDate"));
```

Using usort like this, passing the reference of the function it works. So basically it was not locating the function which usort should use.

also, changed my sortByDate function to this:

```
function sortByDate($a, $b) {
        $first = $this->formatDateDownloadForTest($a['event_date']);
        $second = $this->formatDateDownloadForTest($b['event_date']);

        return ($first - $second);
    }
```

Thank you,
Bica